# Probability of chosing a male and a female to compete.

Tags: conditional-probability

Team A has $14$ females and $11$ males. Team B has $16$ females and $15$ males. The Teams are competing against each other. What is the probability a male and a female are chosen to compete?

Team $A$ selecting a male is $\frac{11}{25}$ $\times$ Team B selecting a female $\frac{16}{31}$.

Team A selecting a female is $\frac{14}{25}$ $\times$ Team B selecting a male is $\frac{15}{31}$. But how do we then combine the two different selections?

Comment: The probability of the union of two mutually exclusive events is the sum of the probabilities of these events.

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to multiply the fractions together:
$$\frac{11}{25}\times\frac{16}{31}=\frac{176}{775}$$
$$\frac{14}{25}\times\frac{15}{31}=\frac{210}{775}$$
Then, to calculate the total probability of either event (as @drhab said), we add the fractions together:
$$\frac{176}{775}+\frac{210}{775}=\frac{386}{775}$$
The fraction is in it's simplest form, so the answer is $\frac{386}{775}$.